# Set one array equal to another without a loop

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

In C++ say we have two arrays:

```
a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
b[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};
```

If we wanted to set, for instance, a equal to b, how can we achieve that without using a loop?

My thought is to use recursion, but I'm not exactly sure how.

Edit: Sorry, should have made it clear I don't want to use the standard library functions (including memcpy which some of you have mentioned)

Comment: What is the result ? a == {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

Comment: You could use `std::array` and `a = b;`.

Comment: Do you mean assign b to a or test for equality? Could you clarify this, since you don't show code for the operation you want?

Comment: Updated my answer as per the edit.

Comment: Why no loops? If you don't explain the reasoning behind the constraint, you're likely to get answers that don't help you.

Comment: If you can redefine your arrays, make your array the sole member of a new struct type, and the struct's default assignment operator will provide this; this is how C++03 TR1's `std::array<T,N>` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With recursion:

```
void copy(int *a, int *b, int b_size) {
     if(b_size == 0) return;    
     *a = *b;
     copy(++a, ++b, b_size-1);
}
```

I don't understand the need for recursion though, using `memcpy()` instead is better.

Answer (score 18):

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int b[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};

memcpy(a, b, sizeof(a));
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the copy algorithm from the standard library.

```
std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::begin(a));
```

`std::begin` and `std::end` are new in the C++ standard library, but they're easy to implement for compilers that don't support them yet:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* begin(T(&a)[N]) {
    return &a[0];
}
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T* end(T(&a)[N]) {
    return begin(a) + N;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::array` (or the equivalent from Boost for older compilers) and the assignment operator:

```
std::array<int, 5> a = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::array<int, 5> b = {5,4,3,2,1};
a = b;
```

Comment: What if I wanted to do it without the built in function?

Comment: @user1693091 Without the built in function and without a loop? I don't understand the requirements. I can do it with the builtin function while standing and with one hand behind my back, but why would I?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `memcpy()`:

```
memcpy(a, b, sizeof(a));
```

Comment: What library is it in? I can't seem to find it in c++.

Comment: [`<cstring>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)

Answer (score 4):

`memcpy` works but you can use [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) also which handily does not explode if you have over-lapping memory locations (not likely in your example, but if you the logic to a "clone" function for example it could happen).

```
memmove( a, b, sizeof(a) );
```

Of course if you are sure about your source and destination not overlapping then `memcpy` is fine.